# WCF Binding for non-WCF TCP Server

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, tcpclient

I have an old non-WCF Windows Service that creates a TCPClient to connect to a non-WCF TCP Server. I can't change the server app at all. It attempts to create a 2 threads, one for reading and processing messages from the Server, and one for reading from an MSMQ queue, processing, and then for sending to the TCP Server. Unfortunately, there are problems, and sometimes if there is a network disconnection I will get two instances of either the read or write threads. The threads share the same TCPClient connection.

Was hoping to switch my service to WCF, hosted by a Windows Service. I know I could use MSMQIntegration binding for a send method, but I am not sure how I could bind to a shared TCP connection. netTCPBinding seems to also be limited to WCF to WCF connections. Does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This is theoretically possible with WCF's extensibility, but you would have to write a custom endpoint, a custom message formatter, and the fifty other classes.  I'd recommend implementing the TCP service separately.

WCF Extensibility is best considered when you are dealing with a SOAP-like service which uses XML-like messages over a standard endpoint (transport).  When you are "pretty close" to that, you can usually patch over the differences.  When you are using none of that, WCF becomes a hindrance rather than a timesaver.  For example, I would use WCF extensibility if:

- I had a SOAP service which needed to run over SMTP or some other odd transport (custom endpoint)
- I had a custom xml format that runs over a standard endpoint (`I*MessageInspector`)
- I had a custom format which can be readily converted to XML running over a standard endpoint (custom message encoder)

I would not use WCF for:

- Any format which does not convert readily to XML
- Any format which does not readily identify the `Action` / target method
- REST services (despite internal support - look at MVC Web API)
- Anything requiring transport of large binary blobs (unless MTOM covers it)
- Services where more than one of the built-in components have to be replaced

Answer (score 0):

WCF library is the library that allows developers to communicate between WCF and non-WCF services in protocol agnostic way. Service developers using WCF don't need to known the details of protocol used between these services because these intricacies are hidden in WCF bindings. So the service developers have just to configure their client or server endpoints/bindings/behaviors correctly and these endpoints/bindings/behaviors do all the labor.

But WCF in not an universal platform to communicate with 'anything'. For instance NetTcpBinding uses TCP sockets to communicate. TCP protocol allows to create a pipeline between both parties but when this pipeline is established, TCP doesn't specify or mandate what content should be send through this pipeline. It can be some standardized protocol like HTTP, or proprietary custom protocol invented by SW developer that has never been published. There are hundreds maybe thousands of custom protocols that can flow through TCP including protocols like Modbus via TCP or IEC104. These 2 protocols for instance were specially designed to be tiny to communicate with the embedded devices and can't be used as the protocols for exchanging universal messages between Web services.

NetTcpBinding sends through TCP pipeline its own completely independent protocol designed by MS to provide efficient communication with WCF services build upon NetTcpBinding. It can't be used to communicate with your custom service using some unknown protocol with different (unknown) data serialization, timing, security, data exchange patterns, etc..

So the only viable option here is to use 'raw sockets' - classes like `Socket` or `TcpClient` to communicate with your proprietary service. But at first you must know what protocol your TCP Server is using. Maybe it's some standardized protocol like SOAP or HTTP or completely independent proprietary protocol that has never been published or documented.

And even though WCF has many extensibility options that allows developers to extend WCF library, these extensibility options are meant to be used when you want to allow WCF to communicate via other transport protocol (UDP, serial line, shared network path) or to add some new features to WCF bindings like new security option some extended transaction support or logging. But extending WCF to communicate with some non-WCF proprietary service (using some home-made protocol) would be inefficient (maybe impossible) and over-complicated.

So if your non-WCF service isn't using protocol that very close (virtually the same) as the protocol NetTcpBinding is using then WCF is not an option here. Use `Socket` or `TcpClient` classes.